# php login script security

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I just wanted to run my login script by you guys to see if there are other security measures that i should take.

I know that i need to move my DB constants to a config file but aside from that and some error handling, what other checks to i need to add to make sure this script is secure?

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require 'phpDatabaseClass.php';

    define('DBhost', 'localhost');
    define('DBusername', 'root');
    define('DBpassword', 'root');
    define('DBname', 'campbellCustomCoatings');


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {       
        if((!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['password'])))
        {
            //creates the db object and the constructor automatically creates the db connection
             $db = new phpDatabaseClass();

            //sets the username and password to variables and sanitizes them
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            //sets the username to only alphanumeric characters
            $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_POST['username']);

            //if the username and password are valid
            if($db->validateLogin($username, $password))
            {
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $username;

                header('Location: uploadImages.php');
            }
        }        
    }
?>
```

and my phpDatabaseClass

```
<?php
/********************************************
* Created by Tom Caflisch
* 
* Class to connect and query a mysql database 
*
*********************************************/

class phpDatabaseClass {

    private $mysqli;

    /****************************
    * Constructor function which makes the connection to the database
    ****************************/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DBhost, DBusername, DBpassword, DBname);
    }
/****************************
    * Function which checks to see if the username and password validate
    *
    * $username is the username that the user entered in the form
    * $password is the password that the user entered in the form
    *
    ****************************/
    public function validateLogin($username, $password)
    {

        //if magic quotes are turned on, remove the slashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
        }

        $username = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
        $password = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

        $password = md5($password);

        //the query
        $sql = 'select * from users
                where username = \''.$username.'\'
                and password = \''.$password.'\'';

        $results = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

        //if something is wrong with the query
        if($results === false)
        {
            echo 'Whoa you trying to hack this thing?';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo $results->num_rows;
            if(($results->num_rows) == 1)
            {

                while($row = $results->fetch_row())
                {
                    //if the username and password match return true else return false
                    if($username == $row[1] && $password == $row[2])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

        //return false;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Why on earth did you call it `phpDatabaseClass` when its major function is to validate a login?

Comment: why don't you return "$username == $row[1] && $password == $row[2]"

Comment: And WhyTH is the classname prefixed with "php"? Does the PHP script use C++, C# or Java classes? And why do you `SELECT *` if you just want to check username and password? And why do you access it by index? What if someone adds a field between ID and username? Why do you even check at all after you already check with `WHERE`? Oh, and why not just `COUNT(*)` and then check if it returns a 1 or 0?

Comment: @MrXexxed there are other functions in the class that i just left out.
@Srinivas why would i need to? If i'm doing the validation in this function i didn't see it necessary to return the actual values.

Comment: @dbemerlin what do you mean why do i even check at all after i already check with WHERE? and does it matter if i check COUNT(*) or check if row_nums > 0???

Comment: @catfish okay, but even with extra methods in your class, what has password validation got to do with the database class? That should be in a separate class and that function then calls the relevant methods from your database class. I'm assuming your db class is used by other classes too or do you have ALL of your methods that might use the database at some point in `phpDatabaseClass`?

Comment: Well this is my first time creating a class so no there are no other classes that use my db class.

Comment: @catfish: `SELECT *` returns lots of data you do not require (depending on your database this can be a big difference), `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns always one row with one column with either 0 or 1. This also saves you the check for the number of rows and it is easier to move into a database-side stored procedure later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use MD5 for hashing passwords, consider using something else like sha1 or whirlpool and maybe salt the passwords as well.

I find this link very useful: http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-password-security it describes how to salt passwords and so on.

Comment: Hashing password is like thinking - ouch, my site is so insecure that everybody can read my database.

Comment: @codez are you suggesting he store the passwords in plaintext? Am I to assume from your comment that you've developed the world's first 100% hacker-proof public website?

Comment: Hashing passwords is more like, "I know I did a lot of work to make sure that my login is secure for my users but I know that there are bad people out there that can and will exploit vulnerabilities that I don't know about. I'll protect my users by salting and hashing their passwords with SHA-1 just to be safe."

Answer (score 2):

Also why alert the user to whether your script has picked up on a potential exploit? Just act like it was an invalid login. The more time they waste on things you've already thought of, the less they have to spend on things you haven't.